# How to save FUNF probes to the remote server?

Tags: android

I have created the funf app that only uses basic probe like wifi and simple location.At the moment the data is saved to the sd card by i want themto be save to my remote server.Thanks in advance

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DataListener {

```
public static final String PIPELINE_NAME = "default";
private FunfManager funfManager;
private BasicPipeline pipeline;
private WifiProbe wifiProbe;
private SimpleLocationProbe locationProbe;
private CheckBox enabledCheckbox;
private Button archiveButton, scanNowButton;
private TextView dataCountView;
private Handler handler;
private ServiceConnection funfManagerConn = new ServiceConnection() {    
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        funfManager = ((FunfManager.LocalBinder)service).getManager();

        Gson gson = funfManager.getGson();
        wifiProbe = gson.fromJson(new JsonObject(), WifiProbe.class);
        locationProbe = gson.fromJson(new JsonObject(), SimpleLocationProbe.class);
        pipeline = (BasicPipeline) funfManager.getRegisteredPipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
        wifiProbe.registerPassiveListener(MainActivity.this);
        locationProbe.registerPassiveListener(MainActivity.this);

        // This checkbox enables or disables the pipeline
        enabledCheckbox.setChecked(pipeline.isEnabled());
        enabledCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (funfManager != null) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        funfManager.enablePipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
                        pipeline = (BasicPipeline) funfManager.getRegisteredPipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
                    } else {
                        funfManager.disablePipeline(PIPELINE_NAME);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Set UI ready to use, by enabling buttons
        enabledCheckbox.setEnabled(true);
        archiveButton.setEnabled(true);

        scanNowButton.setEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        funfManager = null;

    }



};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 // Forces the pipeline to scan now
    scanNowButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanNowButton);
    scanNowButton.setEnabled(false);
    scanNowButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (pipeline.isEnabled()) {
                // Manually register the pipeline
                wifiProbe.registerListener(pipeline);
                locationProbe.registerListener(pipeline);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Pipeline is not enabled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Displays the count of rows in the data
    dataCountView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataCountText);

    // Used to make interface changes on main thread
    handler = new Handler();

    enabledCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.enabledCheckbox);
    enabledCheckbox.setEnabled(false);

    // Runs an archive if pipeline is enabled
    archiveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.archiveButton);
    archiveButton.setEnabled(false);
    archiveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (pipeline.isEnabled()) {
                pipeline.onRun(BasicPipeline.ACTION_ARCHIVE, null);

                // Wait 1 second for archive to finish, then refresh the UI
                // (Note: this is kind of a hack since archiving is seamless and there are no messages when it occurs)
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Archived!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateScanCount();
                    }
                }, 1000L);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Pipeline is not enabled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Bind to the service, to create the connection with FunfManager
    bindService(new Intent(this, FunfManager.class), funfManagerConn, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onDataCompleted(IJsonObject probeConfig, JsonElement checkpoint) {
    updateScanCount();

    // Re-register to keep listening after probe completes.
    wifiProbe.registerPassiveListener(this);
    locationProbe.registerPassiveListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onDataReceived(IJsonObject arg0, IJsonObject arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
private static final String TOTAL_COUNT_SQL = "SELECT count(*) FROM " + NameValueDatabaseHelper.DATA_TABLE.name;
/**
* Queries the database of the pipeline to determine how many rows of data we have recorded so far.
*/
private void updateScanCount() {
    // Query the pipeline db for the count of rows in the data table
    SQLiteDatabase db = pipeline.getDb();
    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(TOTAL_COUNT_SQL, null);
    mcursor.moveToFirst();
    final int count = mcursor.getInt(0);
    // Update interface on main thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dataCountView.setText("Data Count: " + count);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending data to remote server, first you need to configure your strings.xml

file like below.

```
"archive": {
                "@schedule": {"interval": 60}
           },
"upload":  {
                   "url": \"http://example.com/test/android_data_receiver.php\",
                   "@schedule": {"interval": 60}
           }
```

It will send data to server every 1 minutes and also make sure you have added

permission for accessing remote server to Android manifest file

Code for allowing permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

After done the above step please create a server file in your domain, For the

testing purpose I had created a file below. Yo can modify the file as your need.

```
<?php

   $target_path  = "uploads/";
   $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
   } 
   else {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a database on server and some backend function to add data to your remote db. The backend function should be on server, and you can call it from your Android app via HttpRequest etc.. Read about REST APIs

Comment: if i create the database how will i know my fields and again where to put the backend functionality

Comment: what do you mean, how will you know your fields? For example you should write PHP function to call that will open db, and insert a row with your data. Then from android you send HTTPRequest (or POST) and call that function with the data from the app. The PHP function gets the data you sent and returns a response if everything is okay.

Comment: Hi @walters Have you got the answer? if not please ping me I can help you.

Comment: @vipin even now I am still looking for an answer I have tried everything but still cant sve information to the remote server .i would be clad if u can help me thanks.

Comment: Little busy, I will post it before EOD.